# proxychain not finding proxychains.conf Tails 2.3

Tags: tails, socks, proxy

My objective is tor --> socks proxy --> destination

Reason for doing this is to access sites that do not like Tor exit nodes. This is all done on **Tails** I have tried running this

```
proxychains tor-browser
```

As well as

```
sudo proxychains tor-browser
```

Only to produce the following error

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)

(process:10322): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Can't locate proxychains.conf: Permission denied
```

My proxychains.conf

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns 
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
[ProxyList]
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 5160
```

I have only added the socks5 line. I have seen [these](https://tor.stackexchange.com/search?q=proxychains) none of them answer my question and my question is specifically related to **Tails**. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. your proxychains setup will not work, this is not how proxying works, you should probably stop right here as you don't fully
>      understand what it is you are even trying to achieve. You cannot ask a
>      remote host to "chain" a proxy to a local host address, the end-point
>      of the proxied connection (tor exit) should reject any connection
>      attempt to ask it to connect to 127.0.0.1:5160, and even if it allowed
>      it the exit probably isn't going to be running a socks proxy on that
>      specific port and it will fail.

A localhost IP will fail, but he can find many free proxies on the internet that he can use.

> 3. tails uses apparmor to restrict what tor browser can do to reduce the impact of exploits against the browser. this is the source of your
>      "Permission denied" error.

He is basically requesting what needs to be changed in the AppArmor config file for torbrowser in order to get proxychains working with torbrowser. Sure, you can use iceweasel instead of torbrowser, but torbrowser brings more customization for anonymity than iceweasel does.
By experimenting I found that it is not enough to allow torbrowser to access the proxychains.conf file in the AppArmmor config. Proxychains would also hook the network syscalls, which might also be prevented by AppArmor. It would be good if someone with knowledge about AppArmor could figure out what the necessary changes are.

> 4. even if you got your proxychains config right, accepted that proxychains leaked and wanted to use it anyway and disabled important
>      security precautions that protect you from exploitation...it ***still
>      wouldn't work*** because tor browser is trying to use a proxy already,
>      which means wrapping it in proxychains will be trying to tell the exit
>      node to connect out to some random external socks proxy, where upon
>      you try to use some supposed tor socks port being provided by that
>      external socks proxy on it's own localhost interface. It's, once
>      again, not likely to be running one, is it? Never mind the "tor over
>      tor" problem you'd have introduced.

What he can do is just disable the proxy usage within the browser and let proxychains manage the proxys instead of the browser. That definitely works.